# Why is it bad practice to secure MVC routes?

Tags: c#, security, asp.net-mvc-4, wif

The MSDN is pretty clear about [MVC Routing and Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.ASPX#aspnet_mvc_and_route_security):

> The only supported way to secure an MVC application is to apply the AuthorizeAttribute attribute to each controller and use the AllowAnonymousAttribute attribute on the login and register actions.

However, I am considering the following approach:

First, I have implemented a custom Controller Factory that performs security checks based on information coming from our custom STS.

Among other information, the token issued by the STS contains claims describing all the MVC routes the user is allowed to access.

Then I check the user claims within the CreateController method:

```
public class SecuredControllerFactory : IControllerFactory
{
   public IController CreateController(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName)
    {
        ...
        bool isAuthorized = principal.HasRequiredRight(verb, ressource);
        ...
    }
}
```

This way we can configure and update security rules in a centralized manner, without redeploying our applications. Moreover, it fits the "convention over configuration" idea.

Is there something wrong with this approach? I don't see why it is considered a bad practice? Can someone exhibit a concrete security issue with this?

Comment: You would need to describe your custom STS to make this sensible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it is bad practise because it breaks the Single Responsibility principle within the controller factory. The single responsibility of the controller factory should be to select and instantiate controllers.

I would question your reason for going with the controller factory approach:

> This way we can configure and update security rules in a centralized
>   manner, without redeploying our applications.

This is a valid statement if you use the standard `AuthorizeAttribute` that specifies the allowed users/roles in code.

However, the recommended approach would be to derive from `AuthorizeAttribute` and implement your security rule logic in the derived class by overriding the protected `AuthorizeCore()` method. For example, it could look up permissions in a database so you could change them dynamically at runtime.

This also allows you to implement custom logic that gets called when the authorization check fails (`HandleUnauthorizedrequest()` method), which is presumably what you have to do in your custom controller factory when the authorization logic fails (e.g. redirect to a sign-on or error page?)

That way, you get the ability to change your security rules and manage them centrally without redeploying the whole application *and* you don't break the single responsibility of the `ControllerFactory`

ThinkTexture provide a good implementation in their identity model framework, as described here

http://leastprivilege.com/2012/10/26/using-claims-based-authorization-in-mvc-and-web-api/

This allows you to specify a Resource/Action and to encapsulate the authorization logic in a custom `ClaimsAuthorizationManager` in the usual WIF way. If you don't specify the resource and action explicitly in the attribute, the framework gets the values from the  using the current `HttpActionContext`, which is nice.

Comment: With an attribute-based solution, we still need to redeploy if an existing non-secured controller needs to be secured in the next version, don't we?

Comment: Yes, but you should not have any non-secured controllers as such. You always do an authorization check and the decision about whether it is secured or not is encapsulated in the attribute logic (or e.g. in soft rules such as a DB)

Comment: That makes sense, I like the single responsibility argument. If I go with the Attribute solution, do you see any inconvenient to still use MVC routes as the resources to be secured? I mean doing something like that: `Authorize("/Person/Administration", "Administrators")`